# Why don't fighting game tournaments play more rounds?

Tags: competitive-gaming

Here "fighting game" refers to games where both players control one or more characters and try to reduce the other's health to zero, e.g. Street Fighter.

I notice fighting game tournaments are generally double elimination tournaments where each round is a BO3 or BO5. Since each individual game is at most 1.5 minutes long, this seems like a very short match time. You could play the entire BO5 in ~15 minutes (3 games per round, max 5 rounds = 15 games at most). In turn, this means that whenever I watch a fighting game tournament, there's a lot of downtime where the casters talk but there is no game.

Why don't fighting game tournaments play more rounds / longer series such that there is not so much downtime between games? For comparison, a single match of Starcraft 2 could take up to 30 minutes, so a BO3 could take an hour, and there is a lot more game to watch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a consequence of fighting games coming from a more "open tournament" structure, where you're intaking tens or hundreds of competitors and needing to run through them in a reasonable amount of time. A tournament is limited by its setups and its staff, and in theory if these could scale, you could have less pools, more matches, etc.

To use your example, Starcraft tournaments with a set amount of entrants allow for a standardized tournament. GSL groups with 4 players per group and BO1 matches will *always* have 5 matches, leading to a 2-0, 2-1, 1-2 and 0-2 player spread. This allows for the schedule to assume 5 matches, multiplied by the amount of groups. They **need** this certainty because of how long the venue has been rented, how much you've paid for the broadcast, etc.

With more players and setups (like an open fighting game tournament with say, 100 people), you have more opportunities for delays with technology, logistics, hardware, etc. You cannot just "expand everything to BO5" because it may jeopardize the whole event; in most open tournaments, you're only renting that building for the weekend, and you can't just extend it another day without massive, **massive** cost.

A popular refrain is "the FGC isn't esports" which also kind of influences this. If you have a fighting game tournament with invited competitors, you have a control as to how many matches you have to go through — you can then experiment with the format, like team tournaments (Street Fighter League) or Swiss brackets as opposed to double-elimination.

However, these are considerably more rare, as the fighting game scene isn't as large — pro players often have to enter the same open brackets for a tournament like EVO, Combo Breaker, etc, and compete just like everyone else because of a lack of stability and consistent income. Formats with fixed players, pre-qualified or invited, are still relatively new; last night's Capcom Cup X event was BO5 all the way through, and that was uncommon enough that it needed to be stated multiple times.

Because players are less familiar with that, you're also going to get pushback if you suddenly tried to say "Yeah we're BO7/11 now." The pushback from players, teams and managers is a very big thing, especially if their lack of attendance hurts your tournaments' legitimacy. There's a good reason why there's only been one Dota 2 tournament to use the BO7 format for grand finals: it was a 4-3 reverse sweep, and the players never wanted to go through that possibility again.

Comment: *it was a 4-3 reverse sweep, and the players never wanted to go through that possibility again.* Did the players explain why they never want to go through that possibility again?

Comment: @Allure 

*Did the players explain why they never want to go through that possibility again?*

Because [the series took much, much longer than normal](https://liquipedia.net/dota2/2013_WPC_ACE_Dota_2_League), and had to be paused mid-way through for a lunch break (imagine a typical game, from draft to finish, taking about an hour). Players don't like going through that level of mental stress for that amount of time.